# Creating a struct on the stack within a function and assign it to an array's position of an array created in another function

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I need to initialise a variable-length buffer of `struct player`s from within a function. So far this is what I came up with:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct player{
    char name;
};

void players_init(struct player **players){
    *players = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct player));
    struct player p1, p2;
    p1.name = 'X';
    p2.name = 'Y';

    (*players)[0] = p1;
    (*players)[1] = p2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct player *players = NULL;
    players_init(&players);
    printf("%c\n", players[0].name); // prints X
    printf("%c\n", players[1].name); // prints Y

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: since I'm creating `p1` and `p2` from within a function, these two variables should be allocated on the stack frame dedicated to that same function, so when that function terminates, those variables should be gone.

As you can see from my example, I'm assigning those variables to the positions of the buffer `players`, which was created in another function.

I'm wondering why my code works (if it really works), since I'm basically referencing variables that, from my understanding, should not exist anymore when `players_init` terminates.

What am I missing?

Comment: Make `players_init` init one player at a time, and pass it a `char` name to use. Then call it like:

`players_init(&players, 'X');
players_init(&players, 'Y');`

This will likely break your code as you expect, since you'll be overwriting the uninitialized memory that hangs around letting your existing code appear to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are copying the whole struct into the array, it works. If you were just using the address of `p1` and `p2`, then you would have undefined behavior because as you say `p1` and p2` go out of scope.

Your case is trivial, but in the real world just be aware you are doing a struct copy, so you need to know which bits are copied and which aren't

Comment: Ok. So, theoretically I just need to create on `struct player` variable `p` and change its field `name` before assigning, since in any case a copy of the struct is created...?

Comment: Yes. You could replace `p1` and p2` with `p` and initialize the items in the array one after the other using the same `p`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Thanks! Do you know a good tutorial that talks about problems related to this one, i.e. when exactly should we be careful, etc?

Comment: Be very, very careful as John points out, if your struct contains any non-static members, your copy will fail because a struct copy is NOT a deep copy, So if instead, your struct contained `char *name;` with name dynamically allocated, the struct copy (assignment) would not copy the contents of `name` and any array or string local to `players_init` would be lost when the stack frame is destroyed on function return or exit.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ok, thanks for the suggestion, but I've not understood it fully. My _non-static members_ you mean only dynamically memory allocated members, right? If not, then which ones also? For example, if I had a field in the `struct player` which is of a type of an enum, then it wouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Yes, that is a good follow-up to ask. It doesn't mean that they have to be static verses dynamically allocated, it means that the members of the struct must be static members `int, char foo[x], long, double`, etc. and not references. I guess the static members is a poor choice of words. The assignment operator `=` stores `values` (see: [**Assignment Operator**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Assignment-Operators) As long as the struct member holds a `value` it is copied, if it holds a `reference` (a pointer) it is not copied, because it can't know the size, etc.